# Change in "clientwidth" with every browser reload

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, render, dom-manipulation

I was working on this carousel and I ran into a problem where clientWidth is different in console.log(element) and console.log(element.clientWidth) and I want to know why this is happening. When I first save the file both values are the same but as soon as I reload they show different values.

I tried to reproduce the same thing with only text but it doesn't seem to happen with text.

Here is the code if you want to reproduce the problem.

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box")
console.dir(box)
console.log(box.clientWidth)
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: start;
}
    
.fs {
  flex-shrink: 0;   
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="fs" src="https://images-cdn.ubuy.co.in/63ef0a397f1d781bea0a2464-star-wars-rogue-one-movie-poster.jpg">
  <img class="fs" src="https://hippy.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/lagaan-bollywood-movie-poster.jpg">
  <img class="fs" src="https://moomar.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Back-To-The-Future.jpeg">
</div>
```

[You can check this out in codePen](https://codepen.io/Shin_12/pen/zYyRXEm).

Comment: something has to be different in each reload that makes that happen. maybe your styles (or at least some of them) load after JS code or something like that.

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan If we assume that is true then the DOM value should be the same as the value printed but in my case, it is not.

Comment: Please consider creating a runnable snippet showing this behaviour,  images of numbers in the console doesn't really help.

Comment: Protip: if you don't know JS, don't write your own carousel. Just grab one of the million carousels people have already made off the shelf and use that. And then you can select on things you wouldn't have been able to add yourself without first learning the intricacies of JS and HTML like making sure it's accessible, efficiently loads content, etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I appreciate the tip but I just wanted to know why the clientWidth is different in console.log(element) and console.log(element.clientWidth)

Comment: Then I'd recommend [edit]ing your post to not talk about a carousel, but instead really focus on the one thing you want to know. Reduce your code to [mcve] form (e.g. most of that HTML and CSS is not required to show the problem) and show that as a runnable snippet. Your post shouldn't need images, just code that shows off the problem (and adding a link to a real page that shows a carousel is fine, as long as it's [in addition to](/help/how-to-ask) having the minimal code in your post)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I edited as you suggested and I guess this helps. I really hope someone answers my query. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, I'm not seeing that happen even in your codepen. However, one thing to remember is that console logging is not synchronous, so even though the logging order is correct, there is (a tiny) amount of time between your console.log lines being executed and the actual log operation in the dev tools console "happening", and usually when working with value mismatches like this, it's because primitives can't changes, but objects can, so by the time you see the data on the console, the primitive value you pulled out (`element.clientWidth`) may no longer be the actual value after CSS reflow.

Answer (score -2):

document.getElementById("id").style.width= "100%";

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp and take the help

JS + CSS one load which loading the javascript

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).